# Which monomials are "leadable"?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, order-theory, linear-orders

**Question**: Let $k$ be a field, let $f \in k[t_1,\ldots,t_N]$ be a nonzero polynomial.  Which monomials
$m_a = t_1^{a_1} \cdots t_N^{a_n}$ appearing in $f$ are **leadable** in the sense that they are the leading monomial with respect to some monomial order $\preceq$?

**Guess at the Answer**: An obvious necessary condition is that there can't be another monomial $m_b = t_1^{b_1} \cdots t_N^{b_N}$ in $f$ with $a_i \leq b_i$ for all $i$ and $\sum_i a_i < \sum_i b_i$.  Indeed, if this holds, then $m_a \prec m_b$ for every monomial ordering $\preceq$.  My guess (and hope; this would have some favorable consequences in my current work) is that the converse is also true.

**Order-Theoretic Translation**: Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the non-negative integers.  On the commutative monoid $\mathbb{N}^N$, let $\leq$ be the natural "additive divisibility" partial ordering: $(x_1,\ldots,x_N) \leq (y_1,\ldots,y_N)$ if and only if $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$.
Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}^N$, and let $a \in S$ be a maximal element.  Then $\leq$ extends to an admissible (i.e., compatible with the monoid structure) well-ordering $\preceq$ on $\mathbb{N}^N$ with respect to which $a$ is the top element.

**Comments**:

- My guess is certainly correct when $N = 1$; this is a trivial case.
- I finally started learning about Grobner bases this week!  Better late than never.  So I am very far from being an expert here.  I'm aware of a result of Robbiano that parametrizes all monomial orders on $\mathbb{N}^N$ in terms of certain real matrices.  So I suppose the idea is to choose the matrix carefully so as to make any $\leq$-maximal monomial the leading monomial.  But I haven't even thought carefully about the monomial order associated to a given matrix, so it is not yet clear to me how to proceed.  I am however pretty confident that, provided only that my guess is correct, this must be a standard result in the literature, and I would be happy with a reference.

Comment: Nice and very natural question! A monomial $m_a = t_1^{a_1} t_2^{a_2} \cdots t_n^{a_n}$ of $f$ is leadable if and only if the row vector $\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ is a vertex of the convex hull of $M$, where $M$ is set consisting of the zero vector $0 \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ along with all vectors $\left(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\right) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ for which the monomial $t_1^{b_1} t_2^{b_2} \cdots t_n^{b_n}$ appears in $f$. I would guess this is somewhere in a book like Sturmfels's on Gröbner bases or Maclagan's on toric varieties.

Comment: Brief outline of the proof: First direction: If $m_a$ is leadable, but the vector $v_a := \left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)$ is not a vertex of the convex hull of $M$, then this vector is a convex combination of the vectors in $M$, excluding $v_a$ itself. Thus, for some integer $k>0$, the vector $kv_a$ equals a sum of several vectors in $M$ distinct from $v_a$. Thus, the $k$-th power of the monomial $m_a$ equals a product of $k$ other monomials of $f$. But this is absurd, since $m_a$ is larger than all these latter monomials.

Comment: Now for the other direction: If the vector $v_a := \left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)$ is a vertex of the convex hull of $M$, then there is an (affine) hyperplane that separates it from all the other vectors in $M$. Using this hyperplane, it is easy to construct a weighted lexicographic order on the monomials for which $m_a$ leads $f$ (just use the oriented distance to this hyperplane as the first comparison, and then break ties using the standard lexicographic order).

Comment: Note that your initial guess is not true, since (e.g.) the monomial $x_1x_2$ does not lead the polynomial $x_1^2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^2$ no matter what monomial order you choose.

Comment: @darij: Thanks very much.  Maybe leave it as an answer?

Comment: I'd prefer it explained better by a good expositor :)